# Write only float values in QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qregexp

How to write in `QLineEdit` float numbers in range (0.0 - 5.0)? I use qregexp for such a task for example `QRegExp a("([a-zA-Z]{3,30})")` to write user name but have no ideas to write float numbers.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by writing, but are you looking for validation?
 See [QDoubleValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option is to use the [`QDoubleValidator`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublevalidator.html) for such task, since it will not only validate the *shape* of the input but also the *range*:

```
auto dv = new QDoubleValidator(0.0, 5.0, 2); // [0, 5] with 2 decimals of precision
yourLineEdit->setValidator(dv);
```

If you are dealing with many decimals (or if you plan to change the range to a wider one), you'd probably be interested in disabling the scientific notation:

```
dv->setNotation(QDoubleValidator::StandardNotation);
```

On the other hand, and for completeness of the answer since you asked for regular expressions, a general regex for float number is `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`, so for your particular range you can try: `([0-4]?\.[0-9]+)|(5\.0+)|([0-5])`. Anyway, I recommend using the validator, since the regex is more difficult to scale if range changes through the project or in run-time.

Comment: @mark1999 Instead of using a `QLineEdit` and a `QDoubleValidator`, you can also use a `QDoubleSpinBox`. It does a little more like allowing the user to step from a value to another using the mouse wheel.

Comment: @BenjaminT +1. I agree too: a `QDoubleSpinBox` would be a nicer and cleaner solution if the OP can put aside the `QLineEdit`.

Answer (score -1):

Using a regex and breaking up the ranges, 0.0 - 5.0 would be :

`[0-4]\.\d|5\.0`

Expanded

```
   #  0.0  to  4.9
   [0-4] \. \d 
|  
   #  5.0
   5 \. 0
```